# A topological space $C- C$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A topological space is called a $C- C$ space iff the closed sets in $X$ coincide with the compact sets in $X$.

Do the two statements below hold?

> **(1) : Let $(X,\tau)$ be a $C- C$ space  and let $(Y,\tau^{\prime})$ be a subspace. Then  $(Y,\tau^{\prime})$ is a $C- C$ space iff $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$.**
>
> **(2) : Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space  and let $X = Y_1 \cup .....\cup Y_n$, where $(Y_i,\tau_i)$ are $C-C$ subspaces of $(X,\tau)$. Then $(X,\tau)$ is $C-C$ iff $Y_i$ is closed in $X$ for each $i$.**

Comment: Statement (1) is easy to prove. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

The first of these especially is very straightforward; by now you really ought to be able to prove things like it for yourself.

1. If $Y$ is not closed in $X$, then $Y$ is not compact, and therefore $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$ cannot be $C$-$C$. Now suppose that $Y$ is closed in $X$. Then every closed subset of $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$ is closed in $X$ and therefore compact. If $K\subseteq Y$ is compact in $Y$, then $K$ is compact in $X$ and therefore closed in $X$, so $K$ is closed in $Y$. Thus, $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$ is $C$-$C$.
2. If $X$ is $C$-$C$, (1) implies that each $Y_k$ is closed in $X$. Suppose that each $Y_k$ is closed in $X$. Let $F$ be a closed subset of $X$, and for each $k$ let $F_k=F\cap Y_k$. Then $F_k$ is a closed subset of $Y_k$, so $F_k$ is compact. $F$ is therefore the union of finitely many compact sets and is therefore compact. Thus, every closed subset of $X$ is compact. Now let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$, and let $K_k=K\cap Y_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Each $Y_k$ is closed in $X$, so each $K_k$ is a closed subset of the compact set $K$ and is therefore compact. That means that $K_k$ is a compact subset of the $C$-$C$ space $Y_k$ and is therefore closed in $Y_k$. Since $Y_k$ is closed in $X$, $K_k$ is also closed in $X$. $K$ is then the union of finitely many closed subsets of $X$ and is therefore closed in $X$. Thus, every compact subset of $X$ is closed in $X$, and $X$ is $C$-$C$.